# How to fix "The type or namespace name could not be found"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

Visual studio wont recognize certain packages (`Entities`, and `TMPro`, to name a few) and it gives the error: `The type or namespace name could not be found`; **but everything compiles fine**. I know there are already many questions and answers related to this problem, but so far none of them have worked for me.

So the way I downloaded these packages was by using the `Unity Package Manager`, so this makes things even more confusing because I installed other packages the same way, and they are recognized no problem.

**So far I have tried:**

1. Checking the target framework of the packages and the project (all are `.NET Framework 4.6`)
2. Deleting the `Library` folder
3. Checking my Unity version (`2019.2.0a11`)

**Some extra notes:**

- I've had this issue for a long time now (with `TMPro` to be specific; for about a year) ever since downloading it from the `Package Manager` in one of the `2018.X` versions
- In other Unity projects, which are using various versions, give the same result. This leads me to believe it is something to do with my visual studio.
- The `Entities` package shows up on the side, *see picture below*[image: entities showing up on side in visual studio]

Comment: Try putting the respective entities package in the build path (as src) of current project.

Comment: @bit_cracker007 Oops mb, I updated the picture. This is how it was, is it what you were meaning?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VS? For me as well sometimes the "connection" between VS and Unity somehow breaks ... Just to be sure: Do you open that script via Unity or from your hard drive? And is it a script or did you open an .sln file?

Comment: are you sure your VS install has the "visual studio tools for unity" installed?

Comment: I had this issue using the Newtonsoft package Had to pack it into a unitypackage and use the unity package installer and now it works

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled `Visual Studio 2017` installed `Visual Studio 2019` and it fixed my problem. I suspect re-installing like others suggested may have worked too.

Comment: Sometimes generated classes defined by Service models in wxd format are not detected by the project and you need to explicitly add those generated packages as source in current's project build path. It happens a lot in Java packages (Eclipse/ IntelliJ).